# Powershell - stdout from program execution to powershell

Tags: powershell, logging, syslog

I can get output from a program (in this case it's restic on windows) to a variable.
I then split thant variables of lines and output it to a log function I have.  Which actually posts to syslog.

```
$command = & $ResticExe backup $folder_list --tag $tag --exclude-file=$WindowsExcludeFile
for ($i=0; $i -lt $command.length; $i++)
{
    Log($command[$i])
}
```

the restic command when the variables are expanded is something like

```
restic.exe backup C:\users\administrator\documents --tag Documents
```

Ideally I'd like to redirect the output of that command to my Log function as it's happening.  There are options for redirecting command output to a file, but I can't see one that I could use to capture each line for the Log function.

Comment: What is your question? It's not clear here.

Comment: As an aside: PowerShell functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs must be invoked _like shell commands_ - `foo $val` - _not_ like C# methods - `foo($val)`.  It happens to work with a _single_ argument, but breaks with multiple ones, because if you use `,` to separate arguments, you'll construct an _array_ that a command sees as a _single argument_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a call to [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) in order to process *each line* emitted to stdout from a call to an *external program*, referring to each input object (line) using the [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_):

```bash
& $ResticExe backup $folder_list --tag $tag --exclude-file=$WindowsExcludeFile |
  ForEach-Object { Log $_ }
```

If you have control over the definition of the `Log` command, you can modify it to accept pipeline input *directly*, which enables a solution that is both more concise and more efficient:

```bash
# Sample Log command that accepts pipeline input.
# The `process` block is executed for each input object, reflected in $_
function Log { process { "[$_]" } }

1..3 |
  Log # -> '[1]', '[2]', '[3]'
```

See the relevant section of the conceptual [about_Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions#piping-objects-to-functions) help topic.